# Read HTML block form variable,find specific tag element with id,and where find tag insert text ! with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a block of HTML as variable,then i need to find specific tag on this block (variable)for example (span,a,input) ,and create a list of them, and where find those tags , i must put a text 
( for example 9).
i was generated this code but can't insert my text (9) where tag was found.

```
var htmlraw ='<div id="myDiv"><table id="table1"><tr><td><span id="span11">hello</span></td></tr></table><span id="span2">hello</span><table id="table3"><tr><td>hello</td></tr></table><table id="table4"><tr><td><a id="a1">hello</a></td></tr></table><table id="table5"><tr><td><input id="i1" type="text">hello</input></td></tr></table></div>';

var html = $.parseHTML(htmlraw);

var list = new Array();
$(htmlraw).find('span,a,input').each(function(){ 
    var element = new Array();
    element[0] = this.id;
    element[1] = '9';
    list.push(element);
});
alert(list);
// get content

for ( var i = 0, l = list.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    var element = list[i];
    var id = element[0];
    var value = element[1];
    /*
    var results = $(htmlraw).find('#'+id);
    var obj = null;
    if (results != null && results.length > 0)
        obj = results[0];
    alert(obj.id);
    */
    $(html).('#'+id).text(value);    
}

alert(htmlraw);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mkmazid/1uua57ys/

Comment: Why are you using the for loop ? Already the raw html is available above.

Comment: I used 'for loop'  for inserting them to list ....

Comment: Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1uua57ys/1/ 
It works fine as you need.

Comment: use `$(html).find('#'+id).text(value);` but `input` has no `text` so you need to improve logic also. In fact your whole code could be simplified by taking advantage of arrays of elements that jQuery builds internally

Answer (score 1):

**New Answer:**

It seems you have a string of html stored in a variable and you want to find all `a` ,`input`, and `span` tags within that string, and update the value they hold while maintaining the variable as a string.

The problem is you have a string but you're trying to access the elements as `DOM elements`. The easiest thing to do would probably be to have a hidden div somewhere, set it's html to `htmlraw` (creating actual dom elements), manipulate the elements, then update `htmlraw`with the modified html from the hidden div.

```js
var htmlraw ='<div id="myDiv"><table id="table1"><tr><td><span id="span11">hello</span></td></tr></table><span id="span2">hello</span><table id="table3"><tr><td>hello</td></tr></table><table id="table4"><tr><td><a id="a1">hello</a></td></tr></table><table id="table5"><tr><td><input type="text" id="i1" value="hello"/></td></tr></table></div>';


$('#processingDiv').html(htmlraw);


$('#processingDiv').find('span,a,input').each(function(i, element){     
       if (element.tagName == "INPUT") {
           $(this).attr('value', '9');
       }
       else{
           $(this).html('9');
       }
    
});

htmlraw=$('#processingDiv').html();

alert(htmlraw);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="processingDiv" style="display:none"></div>
```

**Original answer:**

Is this what you are needing [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1uua57ys/5/)

To get this working, I changed `$(html).('#'+id).text(value);` to `$('#'+id).text(value);` and selected jquery from the `Frameworks & Extensions` panel in jsfiddle

Also, note that the html in your variable has an error. `<input id="i1" type="text">hello</input>` should be `<input id="i1" type="text" value="hello"/>`

As @charlietfl mentioned, there is probably a better way to achomplish what you need if your more clear about what you're trying to do

Comment: how can i update htmlraw ? for have '9' instead of 'hello' ? 
But I need to have '9' as post of 'Hello' in htmlraw !

Comment: Thank you but i must use this code in .js file not in HTML .